# Broken Packages

Tags: package-management

How can I fix the following broken packages?:

```
root@desktop:/home/karl# apt-get upgrade

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libqt4-designer : Depends: libqt4-script (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.3 is installed
                   Depends: libqt4-xml (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.3 is installed
                   Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.3 is installed
                   Depends: libqtgui4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.3 is installed
                   Breaks: libqt4-designer:i386 (!= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.3 is installed
 libqt4-designer:i386 : Breaks: libqt4-designer (!= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.3) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2 is installed
 libqt4-gui : Depends: libqt4-designer (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.3) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2 is installed
 libqt4-qt3support : Depends: libqt4-designer (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.3) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.

root@desktop:/home/karl# apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libqt4-designer
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libqt4-designer
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 22 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/3,610 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
dpkg: error processing libqt4-designer (--configure):
 libqt4-designer:amd64 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2 cannot be configured because libqt4-designer:i386 is in a different version (4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.3)
dpkg: error processing libqt4-designer:i386 (--configure):
 libqt4-designer:i386 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.3 cannot be configured because libqt4-designer:amd64 is in a different version (4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2)
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqt4-qt3support:
 libqt4-qt3support depends on libqt4-designer (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.3); however:
  Version of libqt4-designer on system is 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2.
dpkg: error processing libqt4-qt3support (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqt4-qt3support:i386:
 libqt4-qt3support:i386 depends on libqt4-designer (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.3); however:
  Package libqt4-designer:i386 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libqt4-qt3support:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqt4-gui:
 libqt4-gui depends on libqt4-designer (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.3); however:
  Version of libqt4-designer on system is 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2.
dpkg: error processing libqt4-gui (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                 Errors were encountered while processing:
 libqt4-designer
 libqt4-designer:i386
 libqt4-qt3support
 libqt4-qt3support:i386
 libqt4-gui
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

root@desktop:/home/karl# apt-get remove libqt4-designer
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libqt4-gui : Depends: libqt4-designer (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.3) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt4-qt3support : Depends: libqt4-designer (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.3) but it is not going to be installed
 python-qt4 : Depends: libqt4-designer (>= 4:4.8.0-1~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

The following is the output of `find /etc/apt -name '*.list' -exec bash -c 'echo -e "\n$1\n"; cat -n "$1"' _ '{}' \;`:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list

     1  # deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120823.1)]/ dists/precise/main/binary-i386/
     2  
     3  # deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120823.1)]/ dists/precise/restricted/binary-i386/
     4  # deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120823.1)]/ precise main restricted
     5  
     6  # See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
     7  # newer versions of the distribution.
     8  deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted
     9  deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted
    10  
    11  ## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
    12  ## distribution.
    13  deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted
    14  deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted
    15  
    16  ## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
    17  ## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
    18  ## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
    19  deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
    20  deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
    21  deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe
    22  deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe
    23  
    24  ## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
    25  ## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
    26  ## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
    27  ## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
    28  ## security team.
    29  deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise multiverse
    30  deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise multiverse
    31  deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates multiverse
    32  deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates multiverse
    33  
    34  ## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
    35  ## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
    36  ## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
    37  ## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
    38  ## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
    39  deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse
    40  deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse
    41  
    42  deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted
    43  deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted
    44  deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security universe
    45  deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security universe
    46  deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security multiverse
    47  deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security multiverse
    48  
    49  ## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
    50  ## 'partner' repository.
    51  ## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
    52  ## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
    53  # deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
    54  # deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
    55  
    56  ## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
    57  ## developers who want to ship their latest software.
    58  #deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
    59  #deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/jockey.list

     1  deb http://www.openprinting.org/download/printdriver/debian/ lsb3.2 main

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/duncanjdavis-download-monitor-submit-precise.list

     1  deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/duncanjdavis/download-monitor-submit/ubuntu precise main
     2  deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/duncanjdavis/download-monitor-submit/ubuntu precise main

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list

     1  ### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
     2  # You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
     3  deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/precise-partner.list

     1  deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner #Added by software-center

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-haguichi-precise.list

     1  deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/haguichi/ubuntu precise main
     2  deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/haguichi/ubuntu precise main

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-musicmanager.list

     1  ### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
     2  # You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
     3  deb http://dl.google.com/linux/musicmanager/deb/ stable main
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Please give the results of this command `find /etc/apt -name '*.list' -exec bash -c 'echo -e "\n$1\n"; cat -n "$1"' _ '{}' \;` . Edit your question and add the results.

Comment: @NikTh - I have included the results

Comment: @NikTh - see my answer below. I just ended up chasing down and removing all the dependencies on libqt4-designer, then updating / upgrading everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to fix it by un-commenting the last two lines in my `sources.list`, then chasing down all of the dependencies and `apt-get -f` removing them, then `apt-get updating && apt-get upgrading` the system. Here's a link to my terminal history if anyone else has this issue with the same packages:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/azpue8lq01eqbp2/broken_packages

and here are the commands I used to fix the system:

```
root@desktop:/home/karl# history 50
  611  apt-get clean
  612  apt-get autoclean
  613  apt-get autoremove
  614  apt-get purge libqt4-designer:i386
  615  apt-get -f purge libqt4-designer:i386
  616  apt-get -f install
  617  apt-get -f purge libqt4-designer:i386
  618  clear
  619  apt-get update
  620  clear
  621  apt-get upgrade
  622  apt-get -f install
  623  apt-get remove libqt4-designer
  624  apt-get -f install
  625  apt-get update
  626  c
  627  apt-get update
  628  apt-get -f install
  629  apt-get upgrade
  630  apt-get -f upgrade
  631  apt-get -f install
  632  apt-get -f remove libqt4-designer
  633  apt-get -f remove libqt4-designer libqt4-gui libqt4-qt3support python-qt4
  634  apt-get -f remove libqt4-designer libqt4-gui libqt4-qt3support python-qt4 kdelibs5-plugins kmouth libkde3support4 lsb-desktop python-qt4-gl
  635  apt-get -f remove libqt4-designer libqt4-gui libqt4-qt3support python-qt4 kdelibs5-plugins kmouth libkde3support4 lsb-desktop python-qt4-gl jovie kde-runtime lsb
  636  apt-get -f remove libqt4-designer libqt4-gui libqt4-qt3support python-qt4 kdelibs5-plugins kmouth libkde3support4 lsb-desktop python-qt4-gl jovie kde-runtime lsb amarok kdemultimedia-kio-plugins kubuntu-debug-installer qapt-batch
  637  apt-get update
  638  apt-get upgrade
  639  apt-get install linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic
  640  apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: Good. Mark your answer as the best answer. My thoughts were if you added any external repository and upgraded essential packages and then remove this repository packages remained in the state where you couldn't downgrade them.