# Can't install the ia32-libs package

Tags: apt, software-installation, dpkg

I'm trying to build an ubuntu embedded linux kernel for Beaglebone.

Part of the build has a dependency for ia32-libs.
When I try to install it it say it needs ia32-libs-multiarch.
But it says its not installable! (see below).
I have tried other solutions from this forum without success.

Can someone explain what is happening and what I can do about it?

```
ian@ubuntu:~/beaglebone2/linux-dev$ sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ia32-libs : Depends: ia32-libs-multiarch but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/216998/broken-packages you may also wish to review: http://askubuntu.com/questions/143904/how-to-install-ia32-libs-on-12-04-lts-32-bit?rq=1

Answer (score -1):

You can find an answer here [What happened to the ia32-libs package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107230/what-happened-to-the-ia32-libs-package)

You can still install it using synaptic

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

then just find your package there