# I can not install packages from terminal in ubuntu 18.04.5

Tags: apt, dpkg, dependencies

When I tried to install Python I got this:

```
$ sudo apt install python3.7
[sudo] password for ubuntu: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgd3 : Breaks: libgd3:i386 (!= 2.2.5-4ubuntu0.2) but 2.2.5-4ubuntu0.4 is to be installed
 libgd3:i386 : Breaks: libgd3 (!= 2.2.5-4ubuntu0.4) but 2.2.5-4ubuntu0.2 is to be installed
 libjpeg-turbo8 : Breaks: libjpeg-turbo8:i386 (!= 1.5.2-0ubuntu5.18.04.1) but 1.5.2-0ubuntu5.18.04.4 is to be installed
 libjpeg-turbo8:i386 : Breaks: libjpeg-turbo8 (!= 1.5.2-0ubuntu5.18.04.4) but 1.5.2-0ubuntu5.18.04.1 is to be installed
 libjpeg-turbo8-dev : Depends: libjpeg-turbo8 (= 1.5.2-0ubuntu5.18.04.4) but 1.5.2-0ubuntu5.18.04.1 is to be installed
 libpng16-16 : Breaks: libpng16-16:i386 (!= 1.6.34-1ubuntu0.18.04.1) but 1.6.34-1ubuntu0.18.04.2 is to be installed
 libpng16-16:i386 : Breaks: libpng16-16 (!= 1.6.34-1ubuntu0.18.04.2) but 1.6.34-1ubuntu0.18.04.1 is to be installed
 python3.7 : Depends: python3.7-minimal (= 3.7.5-2~18.04.4) but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: libpython3.7-stdlib (= 3.7.5-2~18.04.4) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

When I tried apt --fix-broken install.. I got this:

```
$ apt --fix-broken install
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
```

Please help me to fix this!

Edit:
the version of my system is:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

The errors I got after using `sudo apt --fix-broken install` are:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/libjpeg-turbo8_1.5.2-0ubuntu5.18.04.4_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/libpng16-16_1.6.34-1ubuntu0.18.04.2_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/libgd3_2.2.5-4ubuntu0.4_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Edit 2:
I tried

```
$ sudo apt update --fix-missing
Hit:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease                      
Hit:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease                    
Hit:4 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease                                             
Hit:5 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                   
Hit:6 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                               
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
446 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

After sudo apt install -f

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  fonts-horai-umefont fonts-unfonts-core gcc-5-base:i386 gcc-6-base:i386 gir1.2-gkbd-3.0 gir1.2-grilo-0.2 gir1.2-networkmanager-1.0
  gir1.2-nmgtk-1.0 gir1.2-tracker-1.0 gnome-characters gnome-icon-theme-symbolic gnome-keyring-pkcs11:i386 gnome-packagekit-data
  gnome-weather libaio1 libamd2.4.1 libaqhbci22 libass5 libavcodec-ffmpeg56 libavfilter-ffmpeg5 libavformat-ffmpeg56 libavresample-ffmpeg2
  libavutil-ffmpeg54 libblas-common libbluray1 libcamd2.4.1 libccolamd2.9.1 libcholmod3.0.6 libchromaprint0 libclutter-gst-2.0-0 libcryptui0a
  libdirectfb-1.2-9 libestools2.4 libgfortran3 libgif7:i386 libgit2-24 libhardware2 libhttp-parser2.1 libhybris libhybris-common1
  libice6:i386 libicu55:i386 libidn11:i386 libiso9660-10 libiso9660-8 libjavascriptcoregtk-3.0-0 libjson-c2:i386 liblivemedia50
  libllvm3.8:i386 libmedia1 libmimic0 libmozjs-24-0v5 libnetplan0 libofx6 libopencv-calib3d2.4v5 libopencv-contrib2.4v5 libopencv-core2.4v5
  libopencv-features2d2.4v5 libopencv-flann2.4v5 libopencv-highgui2.4v5 libopencv-imgproc2.4v5 libopencv-legacy2.4v5 libopencv-ml2.4v5
  libopencv-objdetect2.4v5 libopencv-video2.4v5 libopenjpeg5 libp11-kit-gnome-keyring:i386 libpanel-applet0 libpaps0 libparams-validate-perl
  libpng12-0:i386 libpodofo0.9.3 libpostproc-ffmpeg53 libqt5clucene5 libqtwebkit4 libschroedinger-1.0-0 libsm6:i386 libsodium18
  libspice-client-gtk-3.0-4 libsrtp0 libssl1.0.0:i386 libswresample-ffmpeg1 libswscale-ffmpeg3 libtbb2 libtracker-control-1.0-0
  libtracker-miner-1.0-0 libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0:i386 libumfpack5.7.1 libva-drm1 libva-x11-1 libva1 libvcdinfo0 libvpx3:i386 libwebkitgtk-3.0-0
  libwildmidi1 libx264-148 libx265-79 libxcb-composite0 libxcb-xf86dri0 libxt6:i386 linux-generic linux-generic-hwe-16.04
  linux-headers-generic-hwe-16.04 linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04 p11-kit-modules:i386 paps python-beautifulsoup python-pyatspi seahorse-daemon
  snapd-login-service wine-gecko2.21:i386 wine-gecko2.21 wine-mono0.0.8 wine1.6-amd64 wine1.6-i386:i386 xserver-xorg-input-all-hwe-16.04
  xserver-xorg-input-evdev-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-input-wacom-hwe-16.04
  xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-video-qxl-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-video-vesa-hwe-16.04
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libgd3 libjpeg-turbo8 libpng16-16
Suggested packages:
  libgd-tools
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libgd3 libjpeg-turbo8 libpng16-16
3 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 443 not upgraded.
20 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/405 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 279851 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libjpeg-turbo8_1.5.2-0ubuntu5.18.04.4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libjpeg-turbo8:amd64 (1.5.2-0ubuntu5.18.04.4) over (1.5.2-0ubuntu5.18.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libjpeg-turbo8_1.5.2-0ubuntu5.18.04.4_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/libjpeg-turbo8/changelog.Debian.gz', which is different from other instances of package libjpeg-turbo8:amd64
Preparing to unpack .../libpng16-16_1.6.34-1ubuntu0.18.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpng16-16:amd64 (1.6.34-1ubuntu0.18.04.2) over (1.6.34-1ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libpng16-16_1.6.34-1ubuntu0.18.04.2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/libpng16-16/changelog.Debian.gz', which is different from other instances of package libpng16-16:amd64
Preparing to unpack .../libgd3_2.2.5-4ubuntu0.4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgd3:amd64 (2.2.5-4ubuntu0.4) over (2.2.5-4ubuntu0.2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libgd3_2.2.5-4ubuntu0.4_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/libgd3/changelog.Debian.gz', which is different from other instances of package libgd3:amd64
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libjpeg-turbo8_1.5.2-0ubuntu5.18.04.4_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libpng16-16_1.6.34-1ubuntu0.18.04.2_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libgd3_2.2.5-4ubuntu0.4_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

After sudo dpkg --configure -a

```
$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
dpkg: error processing package libpng16-16:amd64 (--configure):
 package libpng16-16:amd64 1.6.34-1ubuntu0.18.04.1 cannot be configured because libpng16-16:i386 is at a different version (1.6.34-1ubuntu0.18.04.2)
dpkg: error processing package libpng16-16:i386 (--configure):
 package libpng16-16:i386 1.6.34-1ubuntu0.18.04.2 cannot be configured because libpng16-16:amd64 is at a different version (1.6.34-1ubuntu0.18.04.1)
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37:amd64:
 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37:amd64 depends on libpng16-16 (>= 1.6.2-1); however:
  Package libpng16-16:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: error processing package libgd3:amd64 (--configure):
 package libgd3:amd64 2.2.5-4ubuntu0.2 cannot be configured because libgd3:i386 is at a different version (2.2.5-4ubuntu0.4)
dpkg: error processing package libgd3:i386 (--configure):
 package libgd3:i386 2.2.5-4ubuntu0.4 cannot be configured because libgd3:amd64 is at a different version (2.2.5-4ubuntu0.2)
dpkg: error processing package libjpeg-turbo8:amd64 (--configure):
 package libjpeg-turbo8:amd64 1.5.2-0ubuntu5.18.04.1 cannot be configured because libjpeg-turbo8:i386 is at a different version (1.5.2-0ubuntu5.18.04.4)
dpkg: error processing package libjpeg-turbo8:i386 (--configure):
 package libjpeg-turbo8:i386 1.5.2-0ubuntu5.18.04.4 cannot be configured because libjpeg-turbo8:amd64 is at a different version (1.5.2-0ubuntu5.18.04.1)
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libpoppler73:amd64:
 libpoppler73:amd64 depends on libpng16-16 (>= 1.6.2-1); however:
  Package libpng16-16:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libpoppler73:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libwebkitgtk-1.0-0:amd64:
 libwebkitgtk-1.0-0:amd64 depends on libpng16-16 (>= 1.6.2-1); however:
  Package libpng16-16:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libwebkitgtk-1.0-0:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgs9:amd64:
 libgs9:amd64 depends on libpng16-16 (>= 1.6.2-1); however:
  Package libpng16-16:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libgs9:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libpoppler-glib8:amd64:
 libpoppler-glib8:amd64 depends on libpoppler73 (= 0.62.0-2ubuntu2.7); however:
  Package libpoppler73:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libpoppler-glib8:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of poppler-utils:
 poppler-utils depends on libpoppler73 (= 0.62.0-2ubuntu2.7); however:
  Package libpoppler73:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package poppler-utils (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libmagickcore-6.q16-3:amd64:
 libmagickcore-6.q16-3:amd64 depends on libpng16-16 (>= 1.6.2-1); however:
  Package libpng16-16:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libmagickcore-6.q16-3:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gir1.2-webkit2-4.0:amd64:
 gir1.2-webkit2-4.0:amd64 depends on libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 (>= 2.21.92); however:
  Package libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gir1.2-webkit2-4.0:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of imagemagick-6.q16:
 imagemagick-6.q16 depends on libmagickcore-6.q16-3 (>= 8:6.9.6.8); however:
  Package libmagickcore-6.q16-3:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package imagemagick-6.q16 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ghostscript:
 ghostscript depends on libgs9 (= 9.26~dfsg+0-0ubuntu0.18.04.6); however:
  Package libgs9:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ghostscript (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libmagickcore-6.q16-3-extra:amd64:
 libmagickcore-6.q16-3-extra:amd64 depends on libmagickcore-6.q16-3 (>= 8:6.9.6.8); however:
  Package libmagickcore-6.q16-3:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libmagickcore-6.q16-3-extra:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libmagickwand-6.q16-3:amd64:
 libmagickwand-6.q16-3:amd64 depends on libmagickcore-6.q16-3 (>= 8:6.9.6.8); however:
  Package libmagickcore-6.q16-3:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libmagickwand-6.q16-3:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of imagemagick:
 imagemagick depends on imagemagick-6.q16 (>= 8:6.9.2.10+dfsg-2~); however:
  Package imagemagick-6.q16 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package imagemagick (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ghostscript-x:
 ghostscript-x depends on ghostscript (= 9.26~dfsg+0-0ubuntu0.18.04.6); however:
  Package ghostscript is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ghostscript-x (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1.2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libpng16-16:amd64
 libpng16-16:i386
 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37:amd64
 libgd3:amd64
 libgd3:i386
 libjpeg-turbo8:amd64
 libjpeg-turbo8:i386
 libpoppler73:amd64
 libwebkitgtk-1.0-0:amd64
 libgs9:amd64
 libpoppler-glib8:amd64
 poppler-utils
 libmagickcore-6.q16-3:amd64
 gir1.2-webkit2-4.0:amd64
 imagemagick-6.q16
 ghostscript
 libmagickcore-6.q16-3-extra:amd64
 libmagickwand-6.q16-3:amd64
 imagemagick
 ghostscript-x
```

Comment: You have broken packages. There is no "one fits all" solution. See here for inspiration: https://askubuntu.com/questions/216998/broken-packages

Comment: Is there any command to detect them?

Comment: There are already a few in the output of your question. This may be caused by adding incompatible PPA's, or could also be caused by a previously interrupted installation.

Comment: Can you please suggest commands to fix them? I can not install anything because of this. Plese help.

Comment: Try `sudo apt update --fix-missing`, `sudo apt install -f`, and if that does not fix the issue, `sudo dpkg --configure -a`. Include all commands *and* terminal output in your question - use "edit".

Comment: Hey, I tried them please check the edit and kindly help me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to overwrite ... which is different from other instances of package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/855474/trying-to-overwrite-which-is-different-from-other-instances-of-package)

Comment: not exactly, please suggest a way to get rid of this issue.

Comment: Check the output of `sudo dpkg -l | grep ^..r` If you see core packages, you will have a big problem. Otherwise, remove the packages you see in this list using `sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove --reinstreq`. After that, `sudo apt clean` and `sudo apt update` Again, document the output.

Comment: ```  sudo dpkg -l  |  grep ^..r   ``` shows no output